# Finicky CORS behavior in Python Flask

Tags: javascript, flask, cors

This is my locally hosted [website](http://www.cocostraws.com/).  It needs CORS to run, so I add the CORS header for each API link in my Python code.

[image: img]

You can check the full files [app.py](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12mrz3bOyJTSDyupvo11R5OGPybQCADKI) and [index.js](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12mrz3bOyJTSDyupvo11R5OGPybQCADKI).  This code USED to work months ago without any issue.  Now I bring it back online, and the CORS issue comes up.  I notice if I leave the loaded website for a while (not sure how long, 15 minutes maybe?) and come back later, the CORS issue goes away.  This finicky behavior is driving me nuts because I can't zero in on the exact cause.  I have tried everything I can think of.  Please help.  I really appreciate any insight.

---

PS: I try Firefox, and the CORS issue goes away.  What is going on?

Comment: Do the HTTP requests include credentials, do they have to be authenticated?

Comment: How do I check for this info?  I am just trying to load the website from Chrome (or any browser).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that Chrome and Firefox interpret the `HTTP` preflight request (Method `OPTIONS`) differently.

Instead of using stars `'*'`, try to us explicit values as follows:

```
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', request.headers.origin);
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
```

> For most headers, the value `'*'` only counts as a special wildcard value for requests without credentials (requests without `HTTP` cookies or `HTTP` authentication information).
>
> see [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers), [Access-Control-Allow-Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) etc.